# No output when using HPC job scheduler with GNU parallel

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, hpc, gnu-parallel, lsf

I'm trying to submit a bash script to an HPC job scheduler (IBM Load Sharing Facility) and use GNU parallel to speed up execution at the same time. Basically, I need to run `samtools` to subset a large number of `.bam` files with fixed regions. The actual operations on a single file doesn't take too long, but I'm looking to reduce the overall run time.

This is an example of my workflow, with the job parameters used:

```
### /some/fixed/directory/myscript.sh ###

#!/usr/bin/env bash

#BSUB -J my_job_name
#BSUB -q hpc_queue
#BSUB -n 16
#BSUB -R "rusage[mem=8GB] span[hosts=1]"
#BSUB -o logs/out.%J.log
#BSUB -e logs/err.%J.log

basedir="/some/fixed/directory"

# absolute paths to a large number of .bam files
# none of them in the same directory, so no wildcards
input_bam_files="${basedir}/input_bam_files.txt"

# used across all input files
ref_genome_file="${basedir}/ref_genome.fa"
regions_file="${basedir}/required_chr_start_end.bed"

# fixed version 1.16 on HPC
module load samtools

mkdir -p "${basedir}/output"

extract_regions_from_bam() {
    input_bam_file="$1"
    output_fn=$(basename "$input_bam_file")
    output_bam_file="${basedir}/output/${output_fn}"
    echo "Start: ${input_bam_file} -> ${output_bam_file}"
    samtools view --with-header --reference "$ref_genome_file" --regions-file "$regions_file" "$input_bam_file" | samtools sort -T $basedir/ -O bam -o "$output_bam_file"
    samtools index "$output_bam_file"
    echo "End: ${input_bam_file} -> ${output_bam_file}"
}

export -f extract_regions_from_bam

cat "$input_bam_files" | parallel -j 8 --joblog "${basedir}/extract_regions_from_bam.log" extract_regions_from_bam {}
```

Then I simply submit this using `bsub < /some/fixed/directory/myscript.sh`

I've tested running these (with a small subset of input files) components separately, i.e., using only GNU parallel on the local machine, and then using only the job scheduler without GNU parallel. Both of these work fine separately, yet somehow there are no output files when I combine them.

Am I missing something here, in terms of making the HPC recognise the GNU parallel execution? Or is this simply not possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

P.S: I realise I could use workflow programs like Nextflow or Snakemake, but at this time I'm required to stick to using bash.

Comment: Please see if you can make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example E.g. will GNU Parallel work at all on the HPC?

Comment: I haven't worked with gnu-parallel, but is it ensured that `parallel`runs the jobs with `bash`? So, you did not get **any** output - does it mean that you even don't get the file `extract_regions_from_bam.log`? In this case, I would run the script with `set -x` and see what happens.

Comment: Building off of what @OleTange is recommending, why not first verify GNU Parallel will work on the HPC by implementing a simpler (minimized) test case? For example, adding the option `--dry-run` (to the `parallel` command) will print the commands instead of actually executing them. You could also/or add an `echo` preceding all the samtools commands. It's difficult (if not impossible) to help provide an answer without more specific details like the error messages you are getting, etc.

Comment: @OleTange Really sorry for the late response! As suggested by you & JohnCollins, I tried to create a test case to check this (took several days to work it out!). Ultimately though, I was unable to get the HPC scheduler & GNU parallel to work together. I had to resort to using job arrays instead, which was slower but worked better with the per-user resource restrictions set in place by the IT team. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The simple way to process a bunch of files on HPC is to use Python and create one bash file per input, then submit these to i.e. `sbatch`. But this is an inferior solution compared to Nextflow: finding out which job failed, at which stage and restarting them is a pain in the neck.

Comment: BTW, there is no need to pipe the output of `samtools view` to `samtools sort`. The first one in order to work should have a sorted by position and indexed (`.bai` file). You can output BAM directly using `samtools view --bam `